# Does Range-v3 provide a monadic binding function? If not, how do I provide support for the pipe operator to a custom function?

Tags: c++, functional-programming, monads, monad-transformers, range-v3

Given this code,

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <range/v3/view/join.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/repeat.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/take.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/transform.hpp>
#include <utility>
namespace rv = ranges::views;

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v{0,1,2,3};
    std::cout <<
        (v | rv::transform([](int x){ return rv::repeat(x) | rv::take(x); })
           | rv::join)
               << std::endl; // outputs [1,2,2,3,3,3]
}
```

I'd suppose there's function that does the job combining `join` and `transform` appropriately. If I had to write it myself, I'd go for

```cpp
auto constexpr mbind = [](auto&& r, auto&& f){
    return std::forward<decltype(r)>(r)
        | rv::transform(std::forward<decltype(f)>(f))
        | rv::join;
};
```

but this doesn't support `operator|`, which makes using it a bit less readable.

[Compiler explorer demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fzs367).

Comment: So you want to be able to say `cout << (v | mbind([](int x){ return rv::repeat(x) | rv::take(x); }))`?